# Pointer to a given memory address -C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

basic syntax of pointers: `*ptr= &a`

here `&a` will return the memory address of variable a and `*ptr` will store value of variable `a`

I want to ask, is it possible to make a pointer return a value from a given memory address? if yes what's the syntax

Comment: It seems that you should pick up a [decent introductory book on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  The syntax, etc. of pointers will be covered in the first few chapters...

Comment: For information on Pointers : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: The syntax: `ptr = &a;`, note there is no '*' unless `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Pointers do not "return" anything; they are not functions. Please be clearer about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can construct a pointer that refers to some arbitrary address in memory, by initialising the pointer with the address directly, instead of with an expression like `&a`:

```
int* ptr = (int*)0x1234ABCD;  // hex for convenience
std::cout << *ptr;
```

Be careful, though, as it is rare that you know such a memory address exactly.

The cast `(int*)` is required as no implicit conversion exists between `int` and `int*`.

Comment: Are embedded systems rare?  As this is very frequently used to access hardware registers. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yes, I am aware of that. I use them daily. That's why I said "rare" not "never". That is _one_ use case and frankly I'm not aware of any others. That's why I said it's rare.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the dereference operator `*`. 
For example;

```
int * a = new int;
int * b = new int;
*a = 5;
// Now a points to a memory location where the number 5 is stored.
b = a; //b now points to the same memory location.
cout << *b << endl; ///prints 5.
cout << a << " " << b << endl; //prints the same address.

int * c = new int;
c = *a;
// Now c points to another memory location than a, but the value is the same.
cout << *c << endl; ///prints 5.
cout << a << " " << c << endl; //prints different addresses.
```

Comment: but here we're directly providing value to *a , instead of this i want to provide some memory address to *a , and make it store that value

Comment: Oh I see. I'll add this.